# Unable to put borders on page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html page (actually an electron app) and I'd like to put a border round it like 2px solid red or something. When I set the css of my body to 2px solid red, the border only shows up on the top and the left.

```
body {
 border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Nowhere else. Can anybody help me figure out what is wrong.
I have a fiddle up at: https://jsfiddle.net/5vdmnju2/
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `body { width: 100%; }` to `body { width: auto; }`

`width: auto;` sets the element to occupy all available horizontal space within its containing block. If it has any horizontal padding or border, the widths of those do not add to the total width of the element whereas `width: 100%` will set the element’s total width to 100% of its containing block plus any horizontal margin, padding and border.

Comment: and height to 99% `height: 99%;` in order to see the bottom border

Comment: Sorry I thought clicking on the arrow was the way to make an answer as correct. Finally saw the tick mark below it. Thanks

Comment: No problem,  it's just to help other people who may have the same issue and save them a little time.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `::before` pseudo-element over the `body` :

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
body::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```